# KeyError in Python 3 when looping items

Tags: python, json

The problem with KeyError is when one of the fields within my JSON don't have a value or don't exist at all. To solve it, I put my loop in an exception so it can skip this error and continue with the rest of the loop. However, the problem with this method is when one field is missing I can't print the rest of the JSON data because of that one or two missing item.

**For example:**

Scenario 1:

**JSON format:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Bloomberg",
        "city": "NYC",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```

This scenario1 works fine since all items with their values are available

**Output:**

```
('name:Bloomberg', 'city:NYC', 'country:USA')
```

Scenario 2:

**JSON format:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Bloomberg",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the exception will capture that KeyError and skip it. However, I still need to print that data out regardless of that one missing field. I am looking for an output like this:

```
('name:Bloomberg', 'city field not available', 'country:USA')
```

The exception I used in the loop:

```
try :
    myData = (myJSON [ 'data' ] [ 'name' ] , myJSON [ 'data' ] [ 'city' ], myJSON ['data']['country'])
           print (myData)

except Error as e:
            pass
```

Comment: Dicts have a "get" method which doesn't raise an exception on a missing key.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried that already which didn't work because it raised AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get` method. It returns `None` when the requested key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

```
my_json = {
    "data": {
        "name": "Bloomberg",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
my_json_data = my_json.get('data')
if my_json_data is not None:
    my_data = (my_json_data.get('name'), my_json_data.get('city'), my_json_data.get('country'))
```